# Python: Combining regular expression groups into one inside a non-grouping version of regular parentheses

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

The following code results in

```
>>> r = re.compile(r'(?:\|(.+?)|([a-z]+))<(.+?)>')
>>> print r.findall('hello, stack<overflow> / hello|fluid-<overflow>')
[('', 'stack', 'overflow'), ('fluid-', '', 'overflow')]
```

where what I want instead is `[('stack', 'overflow'), ('fluid-', 'overflow')]`. That is, I want to disregard any group that does not match. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your regex to:

```
r'((?<=\|).+?|[a-z]+)<(.+?)>'
```

Use look-behind to assert the pipe character `|`, while not including it in the main match.

Comment: Then it does not match `stack<overflow>` string, which is not what I want. I want to match both stack<overflow> and |fluid-<overflow> parts.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?:([^|\s]+)<(.+?)>)', 'hello, stack<overflow> / hello|fluid-<overflow>')
[('stack', 'overflow'), ('fluid-', 'overflow')]
```